# Is it possible for a 3 by 3 matrix to use Trace-Determinants plane to see convergency?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am showing in a report the trace det graph if solutions to different equations for linear systems will convert (attractor) or divert (repulsor). Is it possible to draw a 3D graph showing the correlation between the Trace(A) and Det(A) for a 3 by 3 linear system to show if the system will converge or not, in the same way you would for a 2 by 2 system.

Comment: In 3D, the characteristic polynomial has three coefficients instead of two. The extra coefficient can be expressed as $\text{Trace}(A^2)-\text{Trace}^2(A)$.

Comment: In 2D, T = trace and D = det are the coefficients in the characteristic equation $\lambda^2-T \lambda + D=0$. The most natural would be to work with something similar in a 3D representation i.e., (T,S,D) defined by $-\lambda^2+T \lambda^2 - S\lambda + D=0$, don't you think ?

Comment: Yves- I tried that on \[\textbf{A}=\begin{bmatrix}1&-4&-4\\8&-11&-8\\-8&8&5 \end{bmatrix}\] and $trace( A)=5$ , $trace( A^2)=19$ and $(trace( A))^2=25$ giving me c=-6 and using the Cayley Hamilton theorem I get it to be $ c=3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to take into account all the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial, not just the trace and the determinant.

For a $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$, with characteristic polynomial
$$
p(\lambda)=\det(\lambda I-A)=\lambda^3 + a_2 \lambda^2 + a_1 \lambda + a_0
$$
(where $a_0=-\det A$ and $a_2=-\operatorname{tr} A$),
all eigenvalues have negative real part if and only if $a_0>0$, $a_2>0$ and $a_2 a_1>a_0$, according to the
[Routh–Hurwitz criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh%E2%80%93Hurwitz_stability_criterion).

Comment: [+1] I was forgetting this important criterion. Btw: little rectification:  $a_2=-tr(A)$ (instead of $a_1$).

Comment: @S.n Having this possibility to represent phenomenas in the $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ space, It does not prevent you to project things in the $(a_2,a_0)$ coordinate plane in order to retrieve the familiar parabolic and axis limits.

Comment: @JeanMarie: Yes, I meant $a_2$ of course. Thank you!