# Classifying critical points of a system of 3 differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I am doing some mathematical analysis for a research project, and I'm currently at a point where I need to determine what type of critical point I am working with. I have a system of 3 differential equations, of which I have already found this system's one critical point. I'm aware of how we can use the eigen values of the Jacobian matrix evaluated at the critical point(s) when the matrix is $2$x$2$ to gain a classification of the critical point (proper/improper node, saddle point, center, etc.), but my matrix is $3$x$3$ so these rules (as far as I know) do not apply. Is there a way of projecting this nice way of finding the classification of the critical points from $2$x$2$ matrices to $3$x$3$? For reference, my eigen values are $-9.56$, $.977$, and $1.7401*10^{11}$.

Comment: Unfortunately, the linear stability criterion is of no use when the Jacbian has (one or more) eigenvales with real part zero. In this case, one says that the equilibrium point is “non-hyperbolic”, and its stability has to be investigated by other methods.

Comment: But see this, in case you need it some other time: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2178952/is-it-possible-for-a-3-by-3-matrix-to-use-trace-determinants-plane-to-see-conver